# What conditions or properties would matrix $B$ have if $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all $m\times m$ real, symmetric matrices. If $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$ holds, what does that imply about $B$ in comparison to $C$?

If every element of $AB$ is larger than every element of $AC$, then I can conclude that $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$, as trace is just the sum of the diagonal elements.

However, even if every element of $B$ is larger than every element of $C$, I don't think it's necessarily true that $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$. So I'm not sure if it makes sense to compare the magnitude of the elements in $B$ to those in $C$.

Since the trace of a square matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, I was also trying to think of conditions on $B$'s eigenvalues in comparison to $C$'s eigenvalues that would imply $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$. However, is it necessarily true that if $B$'s eigenvalues are larger than $C$'s eigenvalues, that $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$?

Comment: In terms of Frobenius inner product, you are merely saying that $\langle B,A\rangle>\langle C,A\rangle$, i.e. the projected component of $B$ along $A$ is greater than the projected component of $C$ along $A$. I don't think this has any special meaning.

Comment: Take $A=- I$...

Comment: I dont know if this is useful by taking $B=A$ and $C=I_m$.

Comment: @Hyperplane, Taking $A = -I$, we $tr(-B) > tr(-C)$. Can you elaborate more on this? So if $tr(AB) > tr(AC)$, then $tr(-B) > tr(-C)$?

Comment: Suppose $A = I_m$, then the statement is just $tr(B) > tr(C)$ which in itself is not very informative. So , what is likelier to expect is this : if $tr(A_nB) > tr(A_nC)$ for a *suitable collection* of matrices $A_n$, then something (more than just $tr(B)>tr(C)$) can be said about $B$ as compared to $C$. Such statements, because the trace comes under the Frobenius inner product regime, will become a statement on subspaces and inner products in a finite dimensional space, so theory from there will come into play.

Comment: If you don't know anything about $A$ (other that that it's a real symmetric matrix), then no condition on $B$ and $C$ alone can guarantee that $tr(AB)>tr(AC)$. If for some given $B$ and $C$ and some $A$ you have $tr(AB)>tr(AC)$, then for $A'=-A$, $tr(A'B)<tr(A'C)$. So any condition which guarantees that $tr(AB)>tr(AC)$  has to include something about $A$ as well.

Comment: Suppose $A=PDP^{-1}$ diagonalises $A$. And let $B-C=PEP^{-1}$. Then $\mathrm{tr}(A(B-C))=\mathrm{tr}(PDEP^{-1})=\mathrm{tr}(DE)$. Its positivity is equivalent to $\sum_i\lambda_iE_{ii}>0$; a sufficient condition is when $E_{ii}=(P^{-1}(B-C)P)_{ii}$ has the same sign as $\lambda_i$.